# C#/Unity Access Static List From Another Class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm changing a CarController script that has the following function

```
public void Move(float steering, float accel, float footbrake, float handbrake) {
    if (this.tag == "Player")
    {
        Server.commands.ElementAt(0); //Does not work, it does not find Server
    }
    //More code here

}
```

I have the commands list in my Server class as public static

```
public class Server : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text text;
    private IPAddress ip;
    public static List<String> commands = new List<String>();
    //More code here

}
```

How would I access the commands List on my CarController script ?

Both files are in different directories and I cannot move them to the same directory. They are also on a different namespace.

Comment: There is nothing in your `commmads` list. Why would it find it...

Comment: @CodingYoshi In that snippet there is nothing, but by the time the Move function is called there will be data inside the list.

Comment: You're likely missing a `using` statement, which should reference `Server`'s namespace. Or explicitly write `[ServerNamespace].Server.commands[0]`

Comment: Oh i see. It does not fimd the `Server` class. Put the full name of the class (namespace.Server) or use a `using`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by putting all the files in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

`WhateverNamespaceTheServerClassIsIn.Server.commands`

The directory you put a script in has no effect on the code (except for special folders like Editor and Plugins).

Comment: I added a namespace to my Server class and it still does not work. The scripts are also in a different scene in Unity.

Comment: No one said to add a namespace, the class should already be in a namespace. Your task is to find the namespace

Comment: @CodingYoshi `Debug.Log(typeof(Server).Namespace);` `returns Null` after I removed the namespace that I added

Comment: Well thats because it cannot find Server. Do you know what assembly it is in? Are you using visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Server class by adding namespace as the above answer suggested something like this

```
using YourServerNameSpace;
```

OR you can get Server class directly through your serverNameSpace.

```
YourServerNameSpace. Server.commands
```

**But** the actual problem is in your code is that **ElementAt** is not exists in List as error suggested.

```
  Error 7 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a 
    definition for 'ElementAt' and no extension method 'ElementAt' accepting a 
first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So for resolving this error you have to add

```
using System.Linq;
```